# please tell me how i can paint the whole screen in a rimlet?

Tags: blackberry

i am developing a blackberry app. i want to paint the screen. i have implemented this

```
VerticalFieldManager hfmBg = new VerticalFieldManager(Field.USE_ALL_HEIGHT )
            {
                protected void paint(Graphics g)
                {

                    g.setBackgroundColor(Color.SILVER);
                    g.clear();
                    super.paint(g);
                }//end of paint method
            };//end of vertical field manager
```

but tell me is there any other approach to paint the whole screen?

Comment: What do you mean by "paint the whole screen"?  Do you mean how to set the background color of the entire screen?

Comment: yes i m trying to set background color. or set image as background

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea - just put that paint method in your Screen (MainScreen or FullScreen) class instead of your Manager class.  You may also have to add the following empty method to your Screen class to override themes that set the default colors:

```
protected void applyTheme() {
}
```

Comment: can u please tell me how to put it in screen class?

Comment: Well - you're adding your VerticalFieldManager to something via add(hfmBg) - that something is most likely the Screen class.

Comment: i have tried doing it through
MainScreen screen = new MainScreen(){protected void paint(Graphics g)
                {

                    g.setBackgroundColor(Color.SILVER);
                    g.clear();
                    super.paint(g);
                }//end of paint method
};


but it doesnt work

Comment: moreover what to do with class that extends MainScreen?

Comment: Once you create the screen you push it onto the stack using UIApplication.pushScreen()